# Countable union of compact sets is separable?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness, separable-spaces

I have the following construction from the proof of Prohorov's Theorem. Let $S$ be a metric space and choose compact sets $K_u$ in such a way that $K_1 \subset K_2 \subset \cdots$ and $P_n K_u > 1-u^{-1}$ for all $u$ and $n$. Then the set $\cup_u K_u$ is separable. I cannot see any special properties of the $K_n$'s except that they are compact. I cannot find any source that says a countable union of compact sets is separable. So how is this union separable?

Comment: Just choose a countable dense set for each $K_n$ ([compact metric spaces are separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974233/prove-if-x-is-a-compact-metric-space-then-x-is-separable)), and take the union of those.

Comment: What is $P_nK_u$?