# Can $\mathbb R^n$ be compact under certain metrics?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

I noticed that $\mathbb R^n$ is not compact under any norm. I read some sources saying that [any norm on $\mathbb R^n$ is equivalent to the Euclidean norm](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Eryrogers/HW1-solutions.pdf). That is, any norm in $\mathbb R^n$ induces the same topology.

And I also read some sources saying that for any set $(X, \mathcal T_{\text{indiscrete}})$ is compact. But
[indiscrete topology is not metrizable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Indiscrete_Topology_is_not_Metrizable).

I wonder if there is a metric that makes $\mathbb R^n$ compact?

Comment: Let $f$ be a bijection from $\mathbb R^{n}$ to $[0,1]$  and define $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How this makes $\Bbb{R}^n compact$?if $f$ is homeomorphism then you can say $\Bbb{R}^n$ is compact. Why are you letting $f$ be a bijection from $\mathbb R^{n}$ to $[0,1]$ and define $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$?

Comment: @AmanPandey You are confused. The question has nothing to do with the usual topology of $\mathbb R^{n}$. No topology is given and there is no question of constructing a homeomorphism. The space I have constructed is isometric to $[0,1]$ with usual metric  and hence it  is compact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ah! I got it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You should make that an answer.

Comment: @badjohn This question is  a duplicate I posted this as an answer just a few days ago. That is why I am not posting an answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bijection $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,1]$ which we can use to induce a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ making it compact: $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$. Under this definition $f$ becomes a homeomorphism. More generally, the same applies to any set $X$ of cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$.

On the other hand [every compact metric space is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974233/prove-if-x-is-a-compact-metric-space-then-x-is-separable). And so a compact metric space $X$ is an image of $l(A)=\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\ |\ x_i\in A\}$ for some countable set $A$. Therefore a compact metric space has cardinality of at most $|\mathbb{R}|$. Unlike topological case, where compact spaces can be of arbitrary size.

So is every set of cardinality at most $|\mathbb{R}|$ compact metrizable? Clearly finite (under any metric) and countable sets (bijection with $\{0\}\cup\{1/n\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N}\}$) are. Under the continuum hypothesis there is no other choice. But without the continuum hypothesis? I do not know the answer.