# Number of components of an open subspace of a compact locally connected space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, locally-connected

In a locally connected space $X$, one can show that the connected components of any open subspace $U\subseteq X$ are all open in $X$ (cf. Theorem 25.3 in Munkres' *Topology* 2e). Therefore, if $X$ is also compact, then it has finitely many components.

I am interested in figuring out whether we can figure out the number of components of an arbitrary open subset $O$ of the compact locally connected space $X$. My search is motivated by the following fact:

> Let $Y$ be a separable locally connected space. Then every open subspace $W \subseteq Y$ has countably many components.

This holds because $W$ itself must also be separable (by its openness), and local connectedness implies each component of $W$ is open in $Y$, hence intersects the countable dense set $Q \subseteq W$ in at least one point. Since the components of $W$ cover $W$ disjointly, there can therefore only be finitely many of them.

So, I would like a theorem similar to this for $X$ and $O$. I know that it's possible to have $X$ *connected* and yet $O$ has *countably infinitely* many components: take $X = [0,1]$ and $O = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{2^{n+1}}, \frac1{2^n}\right)$. **My question: is it possible to give a pair of $X$ and $O$ such that $O$ has uncountably many components?**

At least in the presence of Countable Choice, such an example would have to have $X$ non-metric, because Countable Choice says that [every compact metric space is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/974233), and then we can apply the above fact about separable spaces. Thus, a side question I have is whether there is a compact locally connected *metrizable* example of $X$ in ZF without choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an ordinal $k$ and consider $k\times [0,1)$ with the topology induced by lexicographical order. This is a very long line (i.e. generalization of the standard [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology))), and we can make it compact by adjoining one element at the "right end" (formally: one point compactification). This extended very long line is thus compact, connected and locally connected.

But I can form an open subset consiting of union of open intervals strictly between each consecutive ordinals. This open subset will have as many connected components as is the cardinality of $k$. And thus without limits.

Comment: This is a great example, thanks!